# How marshal nested collection to json with spray json?

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

Consider a code:

```
val myList : List[Map[String, AnyRef]] = ...

//during spray routing

import spray.json._

complete(myList.toJson)
```

And I got en error:

```
Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for List[Map[String,AnyRef]]
```

First of all why??? Spray [spray.json.CollectionFormats](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/json/CollectionFormats.scala) sources contains:

```
implicit def listFormat[T :JsonFormat] = new RootJsonFormat[List[T]] {
    def write(list: List[T]) = JsArray(list.map(_.toJson).toVector)
    def read(value: JsValue): List[T] = value match {
      case JsArray(elements) => elements.map(_.convertTo[T])(collection.breakOut)
      case x => deserializationError("Expected List as JsArray, but got " + x)
    }
}
```

So every list item *theoretically* can be converted with `_.toJson` call. `_` is `Map[String,AnyRef]`, but `Map` types are also supported. Why my example is not compiled? How to get it work?

Comment: Spray JSON doesn't know how to marshall `AnyRef`

Comment: How do you want `AnyRef` to be serialized? Is the default `toString` provided representation ok?